# IE FF Glitch with Multiple Google Charts in jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, charts, slider

I've been trying to solo this one myself, but I've hit a brick wall. I have a collection of 6 different Google Charts all on one page in a jQuery slider. Everything is perfect when viewed in Chrome, but it's glitchy inside FF and IE. In FF and IE, the first framed Google Chart is fine, but when you advance the slider to a different Google Chart, the legend, hAxis, and vAxis titles are thrown off. When the charts are outside the slider, the graphs are fine. I'm figuring it's some kind of CSS conflict, but I haven't figured it out yet. I've been FireBugging like crazy and can't get a solution. The one thing I've noticed in the iframe that Google creates to produce the Google Chart is the consistency of the x & y aligned by the text tag it uses. It's actually different when inside the jQuery slider. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. The first link below is the Google Chart/jQuery slider combo. The second is the Charts without the slider.

With slider:
http://www.burlington-weather.com/current_weather_conditions.php?cityzip=05401

Without Slider:
http://www.burlington-weather.com/current_old.php?cityzip=05401

PS...yes I did try a totally different slider and I got the same result!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because it is hard to render two SVG images for browser. One of solutions is to create custom animation function using requestAnimationFrame and animate two objects at one frame. There are many tutorials so it shouldn't be hard.